# How to uniquely identify a Microsoft Word table?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm using an Excel AddIn to fill in data from an Excel table into a Word document. The data goes into different Word tables in the document. The table a specific subset of the data goes into is determined by a value in a 'target' column in the Excel table.

So far, there was a static relationship between the value of the target column and the order of the target tables, e.g. everything having an 'A' there goes to the first table in the Word document, everything with 'B' goes into the second, and so on.

Now, users are getting creative in Word, reordering the tables, removing tables, adding new tables for styling purposes, ... - in short, the relationship of "everything belonging to 'A' going into the first table to be found" can't be guaranteed anymore.

Is there a way to set a unique ID for a Word table via the Word user interface (I want users to do this on their own, without having to resort to any macro or addin), which I could then use as an identifier for finding the most likely target table from within the Excel macro?

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any [table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.table) properties in Word that are required to be unique other than the index (and possibly `ID`, but only when the document is saved as a web page).

I'd suggest using the table's `Title` property. Users can set this with:

> right-click the table > Table Properties > Alt Text > Title

And you can access the property programmatically like (VBA example):

```
Word.ActiveDocument.Tables.Item(1).Title
```

You can iterate through the `Tables` collection to find the table whose `Title` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If it *has to be* a unique name, the only option that can be used without enabling features that are normally hidden on the Developer menu is to assign a bookmark to each table.

The consistent way to do it would be to select the table using its selection box and use Insert->Links->Bookmark to specify a name. But the problem side is that Word does not warn the user when they re-use a bookmark - it just relocates the bookmark. So without macros etc., (a) the user could specify any bookmark name and that could upset something else in the document, e.g. a cross-reference, and (b) if they specified the name of a bookmark that identified another table, that table would lose its bookmark - would the user notice? Once the bookmark moved, how would the user find that unbookmarked table?

The problem of upsetting other things in the document could be reduced or eliminated by using a naming convention such as "start every table bookmark name with `tbl_` or `tab_` ".